# While opening multiple textfiles onto different sheets, copy current filename to current worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a code that opens a folder, using File System Object, and cycles through the directory opening each text file in that folder to different worksheets.  As the code loops, I would like it to copy the name of the current text file being used and replace the worksheet name with the textfile's name.

I'm fairly new to VBA. It seems like it could be a simple code somewhere, anywhere, in the loop where it says, "Current worksheet Name = Current Filename".

My Loop (simplified):

```
Set FileText = File.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Do Until FileText.AtEndOfStream

    TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

    'If IsNumeric(Left(TextLine, 4)) Then

    ActiveCell.Value = TextLine
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    'End If

Loop  

FileText.Close
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 

Else
End If

i = 0
Next File
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you close the file using `FileText.Close` add the code `ActiveSheet.Name = File.Name`.

Comment: Thanks buddy.  I knew it would be simple.  Much appreciated